# Display superscript in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am trying to display some HTML in the Django admin that is pulled from a model field.

There is a model like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
   symbol = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=100)
   symbol_html = models.TextField('Symbol HTML')
   ...
```

An admin like this:

```
@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   list_display = ['symbol', 'display_symbol_html']           # overview display fields

   # displays non-escaped html
   def display_symbol_html(self, obj):
      return mark_safe(obj.symbol_html)

   display_symbol_html.allow_tags = True
```

This works for symbols like `&Omega;` but not with HTML tags like this `x<sup>2</sup>`. The display does not show the superscript, just reverts the text to `x2`.

How does one display the superscript properly in the list view of Django Admin?

---

**ANSWER**

Based on the response below, I used the markup from w3schools and Django properly displays it in the Admin interface.

See [HTML Unicode UTF-8](http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_latin1_supplement.asp) for the list of characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try Unicode subscript and superscripts https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts